# Occasional svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.....' svn: E730054: Error running context

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I need help with svn errors E170013 and E730054:

When executing the command "svn checkout..." in command line, I get the error

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.....'
svn: E730054: Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed
by the remote host.
```

However, if I run the same command right after (only in the next 3 minutes), the command is executed successfully without errors, and the source code is checked out successfully.

Otherwise after 3 minutes (approximately), if I want to checkout again I need to run the svn checkout command, get the errors `E170013 and E730054`, 
then run the same command again and the svn checkout works again.

It seems to me that after a certain period of time (3min in my case) the socket between the svn client and svn server is closed, and trying to checkout and/or getting these errors is what actually triggers the connection to be reopened again.

In other words, my issue is that in order to perform an svn checkout, the first will always fail, and only next trys will succeed. After a period of time I need to repeat the same steps again and always do two "**svn checkout**" so the second one works.

My interpretation may be wrong but this is the behavior I get. I hope you got my issue.

I would like please to understand why such svn behavior, what causes these errors and how can I solve the issue.

```
SVN server version: 1.8.13 (r1667537) compiled Mar 20 2015, 11:32:18 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 

SVN client version: 1.9.3 (r1718519) compiled Dec 22 2015, 09:12:06 on x86_64-microsoft-windows6.2.9200

SVN Client running on Windows Server 2008 R2 and SVN server in linux machine.
```

Please feel free to ask any question. I would be happy to provide you more information.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Instead of writing down the link https://svn..... in the svncheckout command, I used the numeric IP address (e.g. 192.168.73.39) of the server instead of its hostname and it worked.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: i managed to solve using this solution too. but i do not understand why does another user in the same network as i am does not have to use numeric IP address? any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For me, `svn` was trying to connect via ipv6 and the remote server did not have a properly configured or ipv6-capable firewall.
Similar chatter on [the mailing list](https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2012-07/0109.shtml) suggests editing your hosts file such that you only ever connect via ipv4 which worked for me :/

Comment: Right, on ipv6 connection I was facing the same issue but when I connected with ipv4 it just worked. I don't have an explanation of why that happened but worked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to check the server log. There have to be clues on the root cause.

Secondly, the problem has nothing to do with Subversion in particular. You have to check the network configuration and make sure that your Linux machine properly accepts connections on the required ports and IP interfaces.

Comment: Or maybe the admin of the repo has 'blocked' his machine?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ  This is not the error message that would be given in case firewall blocks the connection. I'm not 100% sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
> sudo dnf install cyrus-sasl-md5
```

For me on Fedora, you need this package to get the password. Otherwise it just won't find the server repository.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn on IPv6.

Although it is not being used in your machine but some how needed by subversion svn.

subversion was fine on my FreeBSD 12.1 machine. Thinking of making more robust, I turned off unused feature IPv6. After that all kinds of problem started to surface.

So, after that I reinstated IPv6, now everything works perfectly.