# svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL when installing svn on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, svn, subversion-edge

Problem occurred when installing svn on Ubuntu 16.04.

After installing the apache2 server and Creation of repository, after that I got this error while connecting to repository by the following command:

```
sudo svn co file:///svn/repository/

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///svn/repository'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///svn/repository'
```

please help me on this issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Meena.

Comment: The error message says that the repository at the specified path is not existing. Did you check that the directory "svn/repository" is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Occasional svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.....' svn: E730054: Error running context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860183/occasional-svn-e170013-unable-to-connect-to-a-repository-at-url-https-svn)