# svn: E210007: Cannot negotiate authentication mechanism

Tags: svn, centos6

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago) in a docker container.

Executing:

```
$svn co svn://blah.company.com/directory
```

Getting:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 
'svn://blah.company.com/directory'
svn: E210007: Cannot negotiate authentication mechanism
```

SVN version:

```
$svn --version
svn, version 1.9.7 (r1800392)
   compiled Aug 10 2017, 19:20:08 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Could you please clearly state your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Occasional svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.....' svn: E730054: Error running context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860183/occasional-svn-e170013-unable-to-connect-to-a-repository-at-url-https-svn)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `cyrus-sasl`, `cyrus-sasl-plain` and `cyrus-sasl-md5` (optional) packages.

Answer (score 2):

The Subversion codebase returns this particular error (internal code `SVN_ERR_RA_SVN_NO_MECHANISMS`) when the Subversion client libraries are compiled against the Cyrus SASL libraries but, at runtime, cannot find an authentication mechanism which is accepted by the server.

You can see the developer notes about the bit of Subversion's functionality at:  https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/sasl.txt

And here's a link to someone else who run into similar trouble, with hints on how you might fix your own situation:  https://www.question-defense.com/2009/04/29/svn-checkout-svn-cannot-negotiate-authentication-mechanism

I don't have personal experience with this area of Subversion's functionality, but I'm assuming (based on this latter write-up) that it would be useful to know which SASL mechanisms are supported by the server you are trying to access.